# Is it safe to add connection strings to version control?

Tags: node.js, security, version-control, connection-string

I have a [Sails](https://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-connections) app and I wanted to add one of the config files (`connections.js`) to version control. This file has the host and port numbers of the database, but doesn't have any app secrets or passwords. Is it safe to add this to git or would it still be considered bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All connection parameters should be in config files.
You can use something like `config` package to define all needed parameters, their default values and create config files for all configurations you use (such as a development, a production, a tests configurations).

Obviously these config files should not be stored in version control. You can store a template for a default config file.

When some connection params are defined in code then after some time you will have to change them if your version control host changed its IP-address or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, it's not safe to commit/push your credentials to any source repository. It's not even safe to store them in production as plain. A solution is to read values of connection strings and similar items from `environment`. In a `Node.js` it similar to this code:

```
const pool = new Pool.Pool({ connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL });
```

It's a common practice in cloud solutions. Sometime there are even more securities applied. In the `Heroku`, connection string is stored in an environment variable while it is changed each few hours.